# How to split a string over a specific character?

Tags: python-2.7

I have a date in the form of a string, and it looks like this:

```
"21.07. - 10.08."
```

I was wondering how do I split the two into two strings, and lose the " - ".

Something that would make `string1 = "21.07."` and `string2 = "10.08."`

Answer (score 1):

```
string1, string2 = '21.07. - 10.08.'.split(' - ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the String at the "-". This will give you a String array. Concatenate the two array elements together to form one String.

In java this would be:

```
 String[] splitted = stringToSPlit.split("-");
 String result = splitted[0] + splitted[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually don't know Python, but I found [this thread](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/258786/split-string-at-specific-character).

Seems like you can split into a list:

```
mylist = mystr.split("-", 1)
```

Then...

```
string1 = mylist[0]; #This contains "21.07."
string2 = mylist[1]; #This contains "10.08."
```